# MathJax {alignat}: Typo in Warning

Tags: bug, mathjax, spelling, warning

> **Minor bug/typo:**
>
> Warning should say `Argument to \begin{alignat} must be a positive integer`, instead of `... must me a ...` as shown below during an edit.

[image]

(taken from [Bin Packing with Relational Penalization](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/748/123))

Comment: Reported in [2013](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathjax-users/i0lCT0UGrSU/SS6CUPlC7AIJ) and incorporated into the next release, we could use an update. {8(  ]